# Seeking public Web Map Tiling Service (WMTS)?

Tags: data, ogc, wmts

Does anyone know of an "almost always available" service URL for a public facing Web Map Tiling Service (WMTS)?

I'm keen to test WMTS client capabilities without having to configure a WMTS server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> This question has been converted to Community Wiki and wiki locked
>   because it is an example of a question that seeks a list of answers
>   and appears to be popular enough to protect it from closure.  It
>   should be treated as a special case and should not be viewed as the
>   type of question that is encouraged on this, or any Stack Exchange
>   site, but if you wish to contribute more content to it then feel free
>   to do so by editing this answer.

---

Take a look at:

- http://data.wien.gv.at/katalog/wmts.html (see download wtms metadaten)
- [GeoSeer](https://www.geoseer.net) has over 400 WMTS endpoints indexed - all current. If you do a search including the word `WMTS`, it will find only results that are served by that standard i.e. https://www.geoseer.net/s.php?q=wmts+OpenStreetMap
- Kartverket offers all their cached services as WMTS e.g. http://opencache.statkart.no/gatekeeper/gk/gk.open_wmts?Version=1.0.0&service=wmts&request=getcapabilities (Human readable GetCapabilities document)
- WMTS provided by the guys from Swisstopo: http://www.geo.admin.ch/internet/geoportal/de/home/services/geoservices/display_services/services_wmts.html

---

Those looking to test their web map applications against an Esri REST WMTS, please use USGS *The National Map* basemap services, which are published using ArcGIS Server 10.2:

http://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services

Click on any of the services in this directory and you will see a 'WMTS' link in the upper left corner which points towards the getcapabilities file for that service.

An example Tile request from the 'USGSShadedReliefonly' map service:
http://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSShadedReliefOnly/MapServer/WMTS/tile/1.0.0/USGSShadedReliefOnly/default/default028mm/4/7/4.jpg

---

You can find a public APOLLO imagery WMTS available [here](http://iws.erdas.com/ImageX/ecw_wmts.dll?service=wmts&request=getcapabilities). You can consider this an "always on" service

The service is compliant to the OGC Team engine test suite but note;

1. The image tiles returned are generated on the fly with no server-side caching. The server is located in Atlanta, GA
2. To improve performance of web clients, the server can be aliased against iws.erdas.com, iws2.erdas.com and iws3.erdas.com to workaround concurrency limits
3. it does not implement some of the optional components such as the REST interface (KVP only) or feature info
4. ESRI ArcGIS for Desktop 10.1 has a major bug in its WMTS client implementation that will mean no tiles will drawn with the service. This is a bug with ESRI and the way it issues KVP requests, specifically the format param

Comment: The http://data.wien.gv.at/katalog/wmts.html link is dead unfortunately.

Comment: take a look at: https://www.data.gv.at/katalog/dataset/stadt-wien_webmaptileservicewmtswien